# tensorflow cifar10_eval.py error:RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm running the cifar10 network on my PC and after finishing the training and running eval script the following error appears:

```
2016-06-01 14:37:14.238317: precision @ 1 = 0.000
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-adf2ca85bb77>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/py_tensorflow_learning/cifar10CNN_test/cifar10_eval_test.py', wdir='/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/py_tensorflow_learning/cifar10CNN_test')

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/py_tensorflow_learning/cifar10CNN_test/cifar10_eval_test.py", line 107, in <module>
    tf.app.run()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))

  File "/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/py_tensorflow_learning/cifar10CNN_test/cifar10_eval_test.py", line 104, in main
    evaluate()

  File "/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/py_tensorflow_learning/cifar10CNN_test/cifar10_eval_test.py", line 94, in evaluate
    eval_once(saver, summary_writer, top_k_op, summary_op)

  File "/home/kang/Documents/work_code_PC1/py_tensorflow_learning/cifar10CNN_test/cifar10_eval_test.py", line 72, in eval_once
    coord.join(threads, stop_grace_period_secs = 10)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 264, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 659, in reraise
    raise value

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner.py", line 185, in _run
    sess.run(enqueue_op)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 315, in run
    return self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 473, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')

RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

what does the closed Session mean? Should the train.py and eval.py run at the same time? I am new in tensorflow and type myself according to the demo codes https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html

Comment: Does it work when running the scripts outside of ipython?

Comment: I type python3 cifar10_eval_test.py in the terminal. It also have the same error: RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.

Comment: Where does your python script comes from? Can you give a link please

Comment: I am new in deep learning and just type the demo codes again according to the tensorflow example. I can send them to you by email, if it is OK.

Comment: Ok I guess you are using [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html). You should add this info in your question so that people can understand which code you use.

Comment: can you elaborate in what sequence you're running your files? can you successfully run cifar10_train?

Comment: I first run cifar10_train and it works, after I obtained the trained model then I run cifar10_eval. It fails. I upload my code on the github: https://github.com/JianKangtum/tensorflow_cifar10_test

Comment: You can download and have a test. I do not know where the mistake happens. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at [the code you posted](https://github.com/JianKangtum/tensorflow_cifar10_test/blob/119fde74c459a55dbacf898ebf9db62407317730/cifar10_eval_test.py), the problem is between lines 50 and 51 in `eval_once()`:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
    else:
        print('No checkpoint file found')
        return
# <<< The Session is closed here >>>
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
try:
    # ...
```

When the code exits a `with tf.Session() as sess:` block, `sess` is automatically closed, and you cannot use it any more. There are (at least) two ways to fix this problem:

1. Indent lines 51 [through 76](https://github.com/JianKangtum/tensorflow_cifar10_test/blob/119fde74c459a55dbacf898ebf9db62407317730/cifar10_eval_test.py#L76) by 4 spaces, so that they are also inside the `with` block.
2. Create the session without using a `with` block and close it manually:

   ```
   def eval_once():
       sess = tf.Session()
       ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
       if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
           saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
           global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
       else:
           print('No checkpoint file found')
           sess.close()
           return

       coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
       try:
           # ...
       finally:
           sess.close()
   ```