# Creating an ai chatbot, but getting a traceback error

Tags: python, tensorflow, traceback

I'm trying to create an ai chatbox in python. I tried following this tutorial: https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/ai-chatbot/part-1/ but I'm getting a lot of errors of deprecations and getting some Traceback error.
Here's the code:

```
import json
import random
import tensorflow
import tflearn
import numpy
import sys
import pickle
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
nltk.download('punkt')


with open("trainingData.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

try:
    with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
        words, labels, training, output = pickle.load(f)
except:
    words = []
    labels = []
    docs_x = []
    docs_y = []

    for intent in data["intents"]:
        for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
            wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            words.extend(wrds)
            docs_x.append(wrds)
            docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

        if intent["tag"] not in labels:
            labels.append(intent["tag"])

    words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
    words = sorted(list(set(words)))

    labels = sorted(labels)

    training = []
    output = []

    out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

    for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
        bag = []

        wrds = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in doc]

        for w in words:
            if w in wrds:
                bag.append(1)
            else:
                bag.append(0)

        output_row = out_empty[:]
        output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1

        training.append(bag)
        output.append(output_row)

    training = numpy.array(training)
    output = numpy.array(output)

    with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump((words, labels, training, output), f)

tensorflow.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

try:
    model.load("model.tflearn")
except:
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("model.tflearn")


def bag_of_words(s, words):
    bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]

    s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in s_words]

    for se in s_words:
        for i, w in enumerate(words):
            if w == se:
                bag[i] = 1

    return numpy.array(bag)


def chat():
    print("Start talking with the bot (type quit to stop)!")
    while True:
        inp = input("You: ")
        if inp.lower() == "quit":
            break

        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]

        for tg in data["intents"]:
            if tg['tag'] == tag:
                responses = tg['responses']

        print(random.choice(responses))

chat()
```

Here are the errors I'm getting. How can I fix the deprecation errors, the traceback error?

[image]

Here's the text of the error:

```
Run id: VOB3W4
Log directory: /tmp/tflearn_logs/
---------------------------------
Training samples: 20
Validation samples: 0
--
--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 91, in <module>
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py", line 216, in fit
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 339, in fit
    show_metric)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 816, in _train
    tflearn.is_training(True, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/config.py", line 95, in is_training
    tf.get_collection('is_training_ops')[0].eval(session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 731, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5579, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1096, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')
RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

Comment: always put error messages as text, not image.

Comment: The closed session error isn't obvious to me (I've never used tensorflow), but the deprecation errors literally tell you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @furas Updated the question with the error message

Comment: Always copy and paste text, rather than screen shots. Screen shots are not indexable, and are completely worthless for the visually impaired. And that particular image is completely worthless even for me, with perfect eye sight. If you've already included the relevant bits in the text, please just remove the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At start file `"model.tflearn"` doesn't exist and `try/except` should catch error when code try to load this file and run `fit()` and `save()`

```
try:
    model.load("model.tflearn")
except:
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("model.tflearn")
```

but it seems this error closes `tf.session()` so it can't run `fit()`correctly.

If you remove `try/except` with `load()` and keep only `fit()` and `save()` then it has no problem to create model and save it in file.

```
model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save("model.tflearn")
```

After creating file `"model.ftlearn"` you can use again `try/except` with `load()` and it should work if you don't delete file with model.

---

Better solution should check if file exists - but it saves data in few files `"model.tflearn.index"`, `"model.tflearn.meta"` and `"model.tflearn.data-00000-of-00001"` so it should check one of this file instead of `"model.tflearn"`

Use

```
import os

if os.path.exists("model.tflearn.meta"):
    model.load("model.tflearn")
else:
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("model.tflearn")
```

instead of

```
try:
    model.load("model.tflearn")
except:
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("model.tflearn")
```

---

**EDIT:** It seems this problem exists at least 2 years: [RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session in tflearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312698/runtimeerror-attempted-to-use-a-closed-session-in-tflearn)

Comment: Thanks! So basically in the try statement, I should do `model.save("model.tflearn.meta")`?

Comment: doing this: `model.save("model.tflearn.meta")` gives me the same error. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: path in `save()` is correct. Wrong is `try/except`. When file doesn't exists and `try` runs `load()` then it closes session and then model can't save it in `except`. If you use directly `save()` (without `try` and `load()`) then model saves it correctly. Code should use `if not os.path.exists(...)` to skip `load()` when file doesn't exist - but it should use `"model.tflearn.meta"` instead of `"model.tflearn"` because `model.save("model.tflearn")` doesn't create one file `"model.tflearn"` but files `"model.tflearn.index"`, `"model.tflearn.meta" `and `"model.tflearn.data-00000-of-00001"`

Answer (score -1):

try doing this in this:

```
try:
    model.load("model3.tflearn")
except:
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
    model.fit(training,output, n_epoch = 1000, batch_size = 8, show_metric = True)
    model.save("model3.tflearn")
```

Comment: This appears to be the same as the accepted answer. What value does this answer add?