# Rendering OpenAI environment in Tensorforce

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am training an agent to play the HalfCheetah-v1 environment in OpenAI using Tensorforce. I was able to train the agent and get the rewards, but I was not able to actually render the environment after the model finished running. I have saved the model using the following code:

```
modelDir=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "models")
agent.save_model(directory=os.path.join(modelDir, "agent"))
```

This works fine. However, when I want to load the model again to render the trained agent, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

The below code is what I actually used to render the environment.

```
saved_agent = agent.restore_model(os.path.join(modelDir))
env = gym.make("HalfCheetah-v1")
s = env.reset()
done = False
while not done:
    env.render()
    action = saved_agent.act(s)
    s, r, done, _ = env.step(action)
```

My tensorforce version number is 0.3.3, and my tensorflow-gpu version number is 1.4.1. Please let me know how I should fix this error.

Comment: The `closed Session` is not an issue with OpenAI gym rendering.  It has something to do with a TensorFlow session (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568980/tensorflow-cifar10-eval-py-errorruntimeerror-attempted-to-use-a-closed-session#37624604).  It is hard to help more without seeing the rest of your code.