# Error in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have tried below code but while running the session on test data I am getting error

> Run time Error: Attempted to use a closed Session.

Code

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    epochs = 10
    batch_size = 3

    session.run(init)
    session.run(local_init)

    num_batches = int(matrix.shape[0] / batch_size)
    matrix = np.array_split(matrix, num_batches)

    for i in range(epochs):
        avg_cost = 0
    for batch in matrix:
        _, l = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={X: batch})
        avg_cost += l

        avg_cost /= num_batches

        print("Epoch: {} Loss: {}".format(i + 1, avg_cost))

        print("Predictions...")

        matrix = np.concatenate(matrix, axis=0)

        preds = session.run(decoder_op, feed_dict={X: matrix})

        predictions = predictions.append(pd.DataFrame(preds))
        predictions = predictions.stack().reset_index(name='quantity')
        predictions.columns = ['user_id', 'product_id', 'quantity']
        predictions['user_id'] = predictions['user_id'].map(lambda value: users[value])
        predictions['product_id'] = predictions['product_id'].map(lambda value: items[value])

        #print(predictions)

        print("Filtering out items in training set")

        keys = ['user_id', 'product_id']
        i1 = predictions.set_index(keys).index
        i2 = df.set_index(keys).index

        recs = predictions[~i1.isin(i2)]
        recs = recs.sort_values(['user_id', 'quantity'], ascending=[True, False])
        recs = recs.groupby('user_id').head(10)
        recs.to_csv('C:\\Users\\ayush.kumar.jain\\Desktop\\deler\\recs.tsv', sep='\t', index=False, header=True)

        print(type(recs))


        test = test.sort_values(['user_id', 'quantity'], ascending=[True, False])

        #test = test.groupby('user').head(k) #.reset_index(drop=True)
        #test_list = test.as_matrix(columns=['item']).reshape((-1))
        #recs_list = recs.groupby('user').head(k).as_matrix(columns=['item']).reshape((-1))

        print("Evaluating...")

        p = 0.0
        for user_id in users[:10]:
            test_list = test[(test.user_id == user_id)].head(k).as_matrix(columns=['product_id']).flatten()
            print(test_list)
            recs_list = recs[(recs.user_id == user_id)].head(k).as_matrix(columns=['product_id']).flatten()
            print(recs_list)
        session.run(pre_op, feed_dict={eval_x: test_list, eval_y: recs_list})
        p = session.run(pre)
        print("Precision@{}: {}".format(k, p))
```

I am getting below error.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-410-9dabbe5ea401>", line 1, in <module>
session.run(pre_op, feed_dict={eval_x: test_list, eval_y: recs_list})

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
run_metadata_ptr)

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1058, in _run
raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')
```

> Run time Error: Attempted to use a closed Session.Could you please help me to resolve the error.

Comment: The code you are showing above seems pretty incomplete. No reference to data, not a tensor, not a tensor operation. Some numpy manipulation in the middle. What do init and local_init refer to? Is that your own code? Do you understand what is going therein?  Apologies if I am wrong

Comment: Is this the full code of the file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568980/tensorflow-cifar10-eval-py-errorruntimeerror-attempted-to-use-a-closed-session

Comment: i have data frame "df"(50000,3).    user_id  product_id  quantity
0        1         196        10
1        1       10258         9
2        1       10326         1
3        1       12427        10
4        1       13032         3

Comment: i am using tensor flow to make recommendation engine using this data.

Comment: If you're running tensorflow in ipython you'll have an easier time using tf.InteractiveSession() instead of using the tf.Session context manager, which might make it easy to accidentally exit the context, closing your session, and getting this error message.

Comment: In that case do i need to close my session manually or it will automatically close?